# Force preview window in vim to show :topleft

Tags: vim

I use two vim plugins that heavily rely on preview window (one for version control and one for user completion). I also often work with vertical split and some of the time it is in diff mode. Now when the preview window comes up in such state, it will only split off the current column looking ugly and breaking the synchronization if I am in diff mode. Is there some way to make preview window always open `:topleft` *without affecting normal splits?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't. You either have to modify the plugin(s), prepending `:topleft` to the existing `:pedit` command, or you can try defining an autocmd to move a window if it is a preview one. Here is a sketch (that only triggers when the preview window is entered; you may need to add other events to it):

```
:autocmd WinEnter * if &previewwindow && winnr() > 1 | wincmd K | endif
```

Comment: I think it will be enough if I bind something along the lines to some key to fix the window up when I need to. Thanks.